# json_decode thinks a normal string is valid

Tags: php, php-5.3, json

Seems my old server this would return NULL or false...the new server returns the value, weird.

```
var_dump(json_decode("this is a normal string, not JSON"));
```

Output:

`string(33) "this is a normal string, not JSON"`

Expected:

`NULL`

Comment: You are correct, it should return `null` (quick test on http://writecodeonline.com/php/). Did you make a silly mistake somewhere? Like passing in `"\"this is a normal string, not JSON\""`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, returns `null` here. However, I tested it against codepad.org and there it returns the string too. I use 5.3.6. Maybe an update helps

Comment: What php version is on the non-working server? I have a read at the manual page, does [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#98971) referring to 5.2.6 looks similar to yours? IIRC 5.2.X had some buggy releases, might be that?

Comment: Ok, so looks like **[this bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45989)** regarding that particular php version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not really formulated a question, but I try to answer it anyway:

Every software contains bugs. That's normal. We share the code, we share the bugs. What you ask about is a [reported and fixed](http://php.net/45989) software flaw in PHP. Upgrade your PHP version or live with the bug.